# In A-Frame video and video sphere do not work in mobile and tablet devices

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

In A-Frame video and video sphere are not working/playing auto play. As we know that Mobile browser can't auto play its requires a user action to play.
Now i have used the click event to play the video but it's not working/playing in the A-Frame code is below.

Comment: Could you be a little more clear about the problem, and what you want to achieve here. Currently your question makes absolutely no sense

Answer (score 1):

Remove `autoplay` if you don't want your video to play automatically.

```js
var myPlayBtn = document.querySelector('#playButton')
myPlayBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  document.querySelector('#scen01-video').play()
})
```

```html
<video width="320" height="240" id="scen01-video" loop="true" src="https://cdn.glitch.com/237f9e5e-9593-4123-a05c-eff4a2b38f99%2FCaliper_logo_video.ogg?1499957478610"></video>
<img  width="320" height="240" id="playButton" src="https://cdn.glitch.com/237f9e5e-9593-4123-a05c-eff4a2b38f99%2Fyoutube-button-web-click.png?1499343364878">
```

Comment: Just to elaborate in case anyone wonders why this works. The `autoplay` attribute does not take a boolean as a value like the OP has in their code. Instead, the `autoplay` attribute itself is boolean. If the `autoplay` attribute is present at all, it will autoplay the video, but if it's not present, it won't. The problem the OP is having is that they're treating `autoplay` as though it takes a boolean as a value. In fact, it doesn't take a value at all.

Comment: it's working fine in desktop browsers. But not working in mobile browsers. Even after click the play button in A-frame

Comment: @BipinChander Do you mean video isn't playing after clicking the button?